# jqGrid using same dataField for multiple columns

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I have a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) which gets its data in [JSON](http://json.org) format by setting the [url](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) parameter.

Is it possible to create multiple columns and let them display the same property of the JSON response?

For example in one column i want to display the data formatted in one way, in another column i want to display the data in another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The exact implementation depends from the format which you use in the server response. If you use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` then one can use `jsonmap` property in `colModel`. jqGrid uses `jsonmap` **instead of** `name` during *reading* of response from the server. So the solution of your problem could be about the following

```js
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: "mainColumn" },
    ...
    { name: "duplicate1OfMainColumn", jsonmap: "mainColumn" },
    ...
    { name: "duplicate2OfMainColumn", jsonmap: "mainColumn" },
    ...
]
```

Of case you can define different formatter for every from the columns.

If one have to use `datatype: "xml"` instead of `datatype: "json"` then one can use `xmlmap` instead of `jsonmap`.

Comment: When I use jsonmap I get a the 'a circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type' error still? I've added the jsonReader as you suggested